# Warning while modyfing some elements of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I have some problems with modifying some elements of a dataset. I've imported it through `pd.read_csv` then I've added a column of the same length of the other and I'm trying to modifying some elements of this column, as below:

```
dataset['c_grid']=0.227809021
for i in range(17,49):
    dataset.loc[i]['c_grid']=0.232309021
```

It returns this warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

and it hasn't changed the element selected above. I've tried to read some documentations but I have not understood how to handle it.

Comment: `dataset.loc[17:49, 'c_grid']=0.232309021`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have the same issue, to avoid it use the fonction .at:

```
for i in range(17,49):
    dataset.at[i,'c_grid']=0.232309021
```

Let me know if it works :)